# Creating a new table from two or more existing tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

## Question:

Is it possible to create a table in mySQL from two or more existing tables?

## Details:

Can I create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERNAME ( AGE INT NOT NULL )
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERAGE ( NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL )
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER LIKE USERNAME LIKE USERAGE;
```

I can't make heads or tails of [Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
{ LIKE old_tbl_name | (LIKE old_tbl_name) }
```

Does the trailing `(LIKE old_tbl_name)` mean 1 or more occurrences of  `LIKE old_tbl_name`?

If it is possible, then what happens to same name columns, or two primary ids?

**EDIT:**  I am trying to use the schema of existing tables to define a new table, **not** trying to populate a new table with the contents of existing tables.

Comment: Are you just trying to use the schema of existing tables to define the new table, or do you wish to populate a new table with the contents of existing tables?  For the latter, one can use MySQL's [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) syntax.  The `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` syntax you mention will copy the schema of an existing table without any of its data, but you can only specify one such old table (the trailing version in parenthesis to which you refer merely permits optional parenthesis to be placed around the `LIKE` clause).

Comment: @eggyal I clarified the question for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER SELECT * FROM USERNAME, USERAGE WHERE FALSE;
```

You can furthermore specify any indexes you require in the new table prior to the `SELECT` keyword, or rename columns/select some subset as usual on the right of `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (PRIMARY KEY(UNAME)) SELECT NAME AS UNAME -- etc
```

If you want to combine all columns of the same name, just use `NATURAL JOIN`s in your `SELECT`.

See [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) for more information.

Comment: so this basically copies an empty set of rows from multiple tables?

Comment: Yes, but it will use the column names and data types from the resulting (empty) recordset.

Comment: if I use your first suggestion it leads to the problem described at the below link. Do you have any idea why? http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,279729#msg-279729

Comment: @puk: Probably best if you post as a new question, including the full `CREATE TABLE` command you are using and the exact error message you're receiving in return...

Comment: that's alright as I was only curious (used the ol' `set foreign_key_checks = 0 ;` to get rid of it).